# Order of the Galois Group is $|G(E/F)| = [E:F_G]$ where $F_G$ is the field fixed by $G$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I was reading Lisl Gaal' book on Galois Theory and, on page 84, the author uses the result in the title without proving it, leaving the proof to the reader (see below):

[image]

I want to prove the following: $|G(E/F)| = [E:F_G]$ where  $F_G$ is the field fixed by $G = G(E/F)$ and $E/F$ is a finite extension.

I could find a proof of this on Michael Artin's book but, the way the problem was presented in Gaal's book, it seems there should be  simpler proof using the results presented so far there, but I am not able to prove it.

If you could provide any hint I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: What definition of "$G(E/F)$" are you using?

Comment: @coffeemath The group of automorphisms of $E$ that fix $F$, i.e., if $\sigma \in G$ and $x \in F$, $\sigma(x) = x$.

Comment: The theorem by Artin says that if $G$ is a finite group of automorphisms of a field $E$ then $|G|=[E:E_G] $ and the extension $E/E_G$ is Galois. I don't think we need any base field $F$ here. The result is non-trivial and proof shouldn't be left to the reader.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I see... I agree this is not necessary to put a base field, I just wanted to state it as it is written in the book. I feel a lot better to know this is not trivial (I tried really hard to prove it "trivially"). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G=Aut(E/F)=Aut(E/F_G)$.

Every $a\in E$ is a root of $$f_a=\prod_{b\in Ga}(x-b)$$ which is separable, in $F_G[x]$, and of degree $\le |G|$.

So $E/F_G$ is separable, from which $$[E:F_G] = |Hom_{F_G}(E,\overline{E})|$$

Any element of $Hom_{F_G}(E,\overline{E})$ sends $a$ to some root of $f_a$, which is  in $E$.
So $Hom_{F_G}(E,\overline{E}) = Aut(E/F_G)$ and hence $$[E:F_G]=|G|$$

Comment: Thank you so far! That part "So $E/F_G$ is separable, from which..." why do we have this next equation? Is it a well known result? Where can I find it? Also, in the end you concluded that $a$ is sent to some root of $f_a$, but why is it enough to draw the coclusion that $Hom_{F_G}(E,\overline{E}) = Aut(E/F_G)$? And what is $\overline{E}$? Is it the algebraic closure of $E$, right?

Comment: I just made some research and found out that this is a well know result (this one I asked first), so please,just ignore it. And I also understood the rest of the argument. The thing is that it looks very complicated compared to what the book was talking about when it left the proof to the reader. But thank you very much, I am going to accept the answer.

Comment: @Vitor Yes there are a lot of concepts but each is somewhat elementary, algebraic closure, $F_G$-algebra homomorphisms to the algebraic closure, that in a (tower of simple) separable extensions we can easily show that the number of homomorphisms is the degree of the extension, and that in a normal extension any such homomorphism is an automorphism, explaining why "Galois = separable and normal".

Answer (score -1):

Since $[E:F_G] < \infty$ in this problem, wlog $E=F_G(\alpha_1,....,\alpha_m)$. Hence the problem reduces to $[F_G(\alpha):F_G] = |Aut(F_G(\alpha)/F_G)|$ by induction on $[E:F_G]$. This is because restriction map is a homomorphism between $Aut(F_G(\alpha,\beta)/F_G)$ and $Hom_{F_G}(F_G(\alpha),F_G(\alpha,\beta))$. Kernel of this map is $Aut(F_G(\alpha,\beta)/F_G(\alpha))$. Hence
$$Aut(F_G(\alpha,\beta)/F_G)/Aut(F_G(\alpha,\beta)/F_G(\alpha)) \tilde{=} Hom_{F_G}(F_G(\alpha),F_G(\alpha,\beta)) \supseteq Aut(F_G(\alpha)/F_G).$$ Hence we can restrict ourselves to proving:$$[F_G(\alpha):F_G] = |Aut(F_G(\alpha)/F_G)|.$$ Following is an attempt to analyze if this equality holds. This can be done by observing that $\alpha$ is mapped to a root of minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ by an Automorphism and if there are distinct roots of minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ inside $F_G(\alpha)$, we have the equality which is to be proved. We have distinct roots as $F_G(\alpha)/F_G$ is a separable extension.

Editing based on feedback comments below (inspired by proof given by @reuns ) :
Assumption in the proof of $$[F_G(\alpha):F_G] = |Aut(F_G(\alpha)/F_G)|.$$ The proof assume that minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is separable (distinct factors) and $F_G(\alpha)$ is a splitting field of minimial polynomial of $\alpha$.
This can be partially proved as follows:
Since $E$ has all roots of minimial polynomial of every element present in it including $\alpha$, we have : $$[F_G(\alpha):F_G] = |Hom_{F_G}(F_G(\alpha),E)| = \frac{|Aut(E/F_G)|}{|Aut(E/F_G(\alpha))|} \geq |Aut(F_G(\alpha)/F_G)|$$.

The second equality in the above equation is because every homomorphism in $Hom_{F_G}(F_G(\alpha),E)$ can be extended to an automorphism in $Aut(E/F_G)$ and this is an injective embedding and further restriction map for automorphisms in $Aut(E/F_G)$ and quotienting on the kernel of this restriction map gives the equality. The third inequality if equality completes the proof. As @reuns pointed out, this need not be true but i am leaving the answer as it is for clarity to others.

Comment: But $F_G(\alpha)/F_G$ doesn't have to be Galois, need to look instead at $Hom_{F_G}(F_G(\alpha),E)$ (and obtain my answer)

Comment: $\alpha$ being separable element of $F_G(\alpha)/F_G$ is enough i.e, its a separable extension is enough. Are u saying, its not a separable element ? My proof only uses separability.

Comment: $[F_G(\alpha):F_G] = |Aut(F_G(\alpha)/F_G)|$ is not true if $F_G(\alpha)/F_G$ is not Galois

Comment: Yes u r correct, it also has to be splitting field of minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Comment: Edited my answer based on ur feedback. Thanks !

Comment: Your answer is wrong, $F_G(\alpha)/F$ doesn't have to be Galois.

Comment: Hi @reuns i added the proof of the statement we were discussing as debatable inspired by your proof. Please check it and let me know if u r satisfied.

Comment: No, $F_G(\alpha)/F_G$ doesn't have to be Galois, try with $F_G=\Bbb{Q},\alpha=2^{1/3},E=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3},e^{2i\pi/3})$. $[F_G(\alpha):F_G] = |Hom_{F_G}(F_G(\alpha),E)| = \frac{|Aut(E/F_G)|}{|Aut(E/F_G(\alpha))|} $ is correct but $= |Aut(F_G(\alpha)/F_G)|$ is not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! got it.

Comment: $Aut(F_G(a)/F_G)$ is the quotient of the normalizer $N_{Aut(E/F_G)}(Aut(E/F_G(a)))$ by $Aut(E/F_G(a))$. The normalizer is the automorphisms of $E$ that send $F_G(a)$ to itself.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the answer based on ur inputs. I am not deleting it so that it is useful for others who make same mistakes.